# TokuDB storage engine missing after restart

Tags: centos, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB-server 10.0.14 and just had a power outage and hard restart. When coming back up I had to manually remount drives etc. but everything seems intact except I have an error when trying to access a TokuDB table with 'Unknown storage engine 'TokuDB'.

Any clue how this could come about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming TokuDB is enabled in your config (which it would have been in the first place in order to be using it), I'd check the Maria/MySQL logs for a TokuDB startup error.  Hugepages is often enabled by default on CentOS and TokuDB doesn't like that - but it does complain loudly in the log.  I'd suspect something like that.

Comment: Nailed it. Looks like putting this in rc.local didn't handle it, though it looks like rc.local never was executed in this case it still appears there is more to that here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99154/disable-transparent-hugepages

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes is problem of package dependency if you have made some update of package and after restart you have found this issue, try to re-install with appropriate command for the distro (for example: in debian or ubuntu)

```
apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-server-10.1
```

I encountered this issue and the command that i suggest solve my problem. Maybe this can help somebody